# Umount device after bind mounting directories: is it safe?

Tags: linux, mount, fstab, bind-mount

I have a home partition which is shared by mulitple distros on the same box. I'm using `bind` mounts from `fstab`. Each Linux install has something like this:

```
UUID=[...]       /mnt/data  ext4  nodev,nosuid   0 2
/mnt/data/arch   /home      none  defaults,bind  0 0
/mnt/data/files  /files     none  defaults,bind  0 0
```

The disadvantage is, of course, that `/mnt/data/arch` and `/mnt/data/files` are now mounted twice. On a hunch, I tried `umount /mnt/data`, which seems to work as I had hoped: according to `mount`, the device is now only mounted to `/home` and `/files`.

My questions are:

1. Is this **safe**, or am I overlooking something?
2. Is it possible to get the same effect as `umount /mnt/data` using only `fstab`? Or could I do it in `rc.local`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's safe to unmount one of the bind-mounted copies. After you run `mount --bind /foo /bar`, the kernel doesn't keep track of which of `/foo` or `/bar` came first, they're two mount points for the same filesystem (or part of a filesystem).

Note that if `/foo` is a mount point but `/foo/wibble` isn't, `mount --bind /foo/wibble /bar` makes `/bar` point to a part of the filesystem that's mounted on `/foo`. It's still ok to unmount `/foo`.

So if you mount `/mnt/data`, then bind parts of it to `/home` and `/files`, and unmount `/mnt/data`, you end up with no access to the parts of `/mnt/data` outside `arch` and `files`. If that doesn't bother you, go for it.

You can't achieve that through `fstab`: it only supports mounting filesystems. Bind mounts get in through a hack (the `bind` mount option is turned into a `--bind` option to the `mount` command internally). `mount --move` and unmounting can't be specified in `fstab`. You can use `/etc/rc.local` to call `umount`.

Comment: Inaccessibility of anything other than `arch` and `files` was exactly what I was going for. Thanks for the confirmation. :-)